# wpf textbox errortemplates in a Managed Addin Framework Addin

Tags: wpf, maf

I've created a textbox style to contain a validation.errortemplate for use in a UserControl class.  If the UserControl is loaded in the normal, non-MAF way, I can see the validation rule kicking in and getting visual feedback (thick red border, a circular bang to the right of the textbox, and an error message-in-a-tooltip) -- everything works the way I expect it to.

However... if I load that same UserControl in as an AddIn, I lose the visuals.  (I do see the error tooltip behaving correctly, so I know my validation rule is firing; I just don't see the border and bang symbol.

My AddIn, by the way, is based on MSDN's example for an 'addin-which-provides-a-usercontrol.'

I know a few of the limitations of an AddIn (e.g., video won't play in an AddIn UserControl); is this another limitation, or am I screwing up?

Thanks in advance!

[Update -- I removed the error template from my UserControl.Resources -- as I suspected, in the non-MAF version, this causes the validation failure to result in the 'standard,' thin red border around the textbox.  However, no such red border shows up in the MAF version.  Ergo, the TextBox.Style seems to have been ruled out as the culprit.]

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by enclosing the fields I want to validate within an AdornerDecorator tag... go figure :-)